# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{T} t^{m-1}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-ut}\,\mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integration-by-parts

> **Task:** Compute the following integral.
>
> $$\int_{0}^{T} t^{m-1}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{-ut}\,\mathrm{d}t $$

Comment: The symbol $*$ means "times" in the above, correct? Also, $t$ appears as an upper bound of integration and as the dummy variable. I assume this is a mistake.

Comment: Use Reduction formulae or gamma functions...

Comment: There is no nice form without the incomplete gamma function, I think.

Comment: I've seen t appear in the integration bounds in order to rid of the constant of integration and keep the function in terms of t. Doesn't necessarily have to be a mistake.

Comment: It is standard usage.

Comment: The function can most closely be identified as the lower incomplete Gamma function $\gamma(n,T)$. Do a change of variables and see the closed form approximations http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Reduction formulae or gamma functions...

Integrate by parts
treating polynomial as first function and exponential part as second function.then use recurrence relation.

set $ut=z, t=\frac{z}{u}, dt=\frac{dz}{u}$
$\int t^{m-1} \textrm e^{-ut} \textrm dt= \frac{\int z^{m-1} \textrm e^{-z} \textrm dz}{u^m}=\frac{I_m}{u^m}$
where $I_m=\int z^{m-1} \textrm e^{-z} \textrm dz$
Integrate $I_m$ by part

$I_m=z^{m-1}e^{-z}+(m-1)\int z^{m-2} \textrm e^{-z} \textrm dz=z^{m-1}e^{-z}+(m-1)I_{m-1}$
Now replace $m$ by $m-1$

$I_{m-1}=z^{m-2}e^{-z}+(m-2)I_{m-2}$
$I_1=0$ and $I_2=ze^{-z}$
replacing these values, we get
$I_m=e^{-z}[z^{m-1} +(m-1) z^{m-2}+(m-1)(m-2) z^{m-3}+···+(m-1)!]$...
Put this value in original integral you are done 
and finally put limits.

Answer (score 1):

For $m=0$, 
$$
a_{0}=\int_{0}^{T}e^{-ut}dt=-\frac{e^{-ut}}{u}\mid_{0}^{T}=\frac{1}{u}\left(1-e^{-uT}\right)
$$
For integer $m\geq1$,
\begin{align*}
a_{m} & =\int_{0}^{T}t^{m}e^{-ut}dt\\
 & =-t^{m}\frac{e^{-ut}}{u}\mid_{0}^{T}+\frac{m}{u}\int_{0}^{T}t^{m-1}e^{-ut}dt\\
 & =-T^{m}\frac{e^{-uT}}{u}+\frac{m}{u}a_{m-1}.
\end{align*}
This gives you a recurrence relation for $a_{m}$, which is probably most amenable to computation (please double check my math; IBP is prone to errors).

---

Also, [Wolfram computes this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bt%5Em*Exp%5B-u*t%5D,%7Bt,0,T%7D%5D) as
$$
a_{m}=\frac{\Gamma(m+1)-\Gamma(m+1,uT)}{u^{m+1}}
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the incomplete gamma function. I believe this holds for noninteger $m$ too.